# React, Jest, test components that render in different screen sizes with MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am trying to test a React Component that can has two different renderings/classes depending on the screen size. I am using Material UI useMediaQuery to detect screen size. Using Jest I can see only 1 condition is tested (full screen size) vs mobile size. Is there a way to change screen size for Jest so it renders the component as if the width was less than 960px.

index.js

```
 const ste960 = useMediaQuery('(max-width:960px)');

    return (
        <div
            className={`${classes.emptyBlock} ${
                ste960 ? classes.unsetWidth : ''
            }`}
            onClick={onClick}
        >
```

index.test.js

```
 test('snapshot renders for Test', () => {

    const component = renderer.create(<Test />).toJSON();
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: Let me know if you had solved this